# Mobile app integration with backend server with offline access

Tags: ios, core-data, mobile, database-design

A little design question here:

The requirements for the system go as follows:

- all the content is stored on the backend in a database
- the client(mobile app) downloads all of the data to have a local copy for offline access

The database on the backend is quite complex and contains entities/fields which are not(at least not currently) used in the mobile client.

What is the right way to design the local database ? Do I need to create a mirror copy of the backend database on the client ? Do I need to create my own data model regardless of what is on the backend ? Should there be any similarities between the two data models at all ?

Comment: Is the local database more-or-less a read-only offline cache, or will the app be modifying it and sending back changes?  Generally speaking, you'd want to minimize your client design to include only what is necessary, but schema changes = data migration if you have to preserve user-created data when the app is updated. Assuming you will wrap the backend DB queries in a web API, you may want to look into MMRecord, which handles storing web API responses in CoreData. https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord

Comment: Does the server data structure represent the app usage? Also, RestKit.

Comment: @KeithKurak thanks a lot for the input. The local database will serve exactly as an offline cache, since a user is not creating any data. The thing is the database on the backend has a lot of different tables to allow the model to be flexible with regards to possible change. I wonder if I should follow the same model, or just create an app-only model with a database generated in a way which best suits the client, ignoring what might happen on the backend. That said, if things change on the backend, that might require a lot of work on the client too ?

Comment: @Wain in this instance what is more suitable for use - RestKit or MMRecord. I haven't worked with any of these, but my understanding is that RestKit is a further abstraction than MMRecord - so what are the benefits of using MMRecord since RestKit seems much more 'powerful'.

Comment: @Wain I am not sure I understand your question - what exactly do you mean by 'data usage' ?

Comment: How is the app displaying the data and how does the structure that makes sense for that compare to the server structure? RestKit allows you to perform an 'arbitrary' mapping between the server and the local data (so they can be different structures, within bounds)

Comment: @Wain Essentially we have the concept of a product and a product has a set of different attributes. On the backend these attributes are modelled into different categories and subcategories according to their specific characteristics. However, on the client, I need to display a 'flat' view of each product with all their attributes into 1 place. Hope this makes sense.